# How to edit the pre uploaded full text article on ResearchGate

Tags: publications, research-process, journals, paper-submission, online-publication

I found my article pre uploaded on ResearchGate.

But the fact is, I updated it and republished it in the same journal and it has same DOI.

I want to delete the older version of the article from ResearchGate and upload a new one.

Is there any way to do this or ResearchGate updates it automatically?

Comment: Contact researchgate. If they know about the problem they may fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no solution to this as of now.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but it appears you always have the option of adding files. So, uploading the new version should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to replace the old full text, do this:
Select the research item >
Click on the downward-facing arrow underneath/beside the item's title ("More V") >
Select "Remove" >
Select "Remove my public full-text" >
Upload the new full text by scrolling down and clicking "Add full-text publicly"

OR

(I haven't tried this yet) Upload the new version to the last version ("More" > "Add file" > "Add a new full text"), then delete the previous version of the text if it still exists.